# Contact Form 7 - Stubborn Checkbox Text Color - Salient Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, checkbox

I've styled most of the contact form without issue but this last little text color change has me stumped.

Basically the checkbox text appears to be inheriting the "primary Salient theme accent color" which is also used for links. The checkbox text is green and I want it grey.

Page: http://amzoptimized.com/order-form/

Spreadsheet additions (getting pretty messy down the bottom):

```
.wpcf7-submit {
font-size:16px !important;
padding:10px 20px 10px 20px !important;
background-color:#A3CB2A !important;
font-weight:500; !important;
color: white !important;
}
.interval {
font-size:14px !important;
}
span.wpcf7-list-item {
  display: block !important;
}
.wpcf7 input[type="text"],
.wpcf7 input[type="email"],
.wpcf7 input[type="url"],
.wpcf7 textarea
{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px #dedede solid;
}
.wpcf7 input[type="checkbox"],
.wpcf7-checkbox,
.wpcf7-form-control,
span.wpcf7-list-item-label,
.wpcf7-list-item,
span.wpcf7-list-item,
.wpcf7-form checkbox,
.wpcf7-list-item-label {
  color: #696969 !important;
}
.wpcf7-textarea {
height: 5em;
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
GS

Comment: You can use jQuery: $("span.wpcf7-list-item-label").css("color","#111!important");

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq no because then all other span with this class will get gray color. like in above section, other checkbox text will be Gray instead of green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#wpcf7-f1361-p1352-o1 form > div > p:nth-child(2) > span > span > span> label span{
    color: #696969 !important;
}
```